# How to full query on elastic about Chinese characters

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, resthighlevelclient

I want to do the full match query on elastic 
here is the data:

```
{
  "organizationId": "ec1c691a4b43e65aebdb2ab9481",
  "organizationName": "工業區"
}
```

If I use this code

```
QueryBuilder QueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery("organizationName","工");
```

it will get the data, but it's unreasonable

And I have try the following 2 code

```
QueryBuilder QueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("organizationName","工業");
```

```
QueryBuilder QueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("organizationName","業區");
```

Both return the data, but it's not full match

Can anyone help! Tks

Comment: what is your expected output ? and what is your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ElasticSearch documentation about [term queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html):

> Avoid using the term query for text fields.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
>   analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
>   difficult.
>
> To search text field values, use the match query instead.

The [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) is the standard query for performing a full-text search, including options for fuzzy matching.

So in your example I would do the following to have exact matching behaviour

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery("organizationName", "工業區")
```

If you only query a part of the name, like 工業 or 業區 ElasticSearch wont return results.

Comment: last I use matchPhraseQuery, because when I input "工區", I expect it return null, but matchQuery still return the data. Still thank your answer! @ksclfanatic

Comment: Did you map your field organizationName as text or as keyword?

Comment: I think I know how to do it! @ ksclfanatic